# video_player aspect ratio for m3u8 videos is different from mp4 videos on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, m3u8, video-player, flutter-video-player

I moved the videos from my app from mp4 format to m3u8 using Cloudflare Stream API. I noticed that on iOS some videos have incorrect aspect ratio and look zoomed in (not a problem on Android).

I found the following thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97206 that has this same issue and what I understood is to use `video_player: 2.2.11` version since what I have now is `video_player: 2.2.7`. I changed the version but that did not solve the issue. I also tried the latest version now which is `video_player: 2.4.5` but still have the same problem.

If someone has idea on how to potentially solve it could you please let me know. I am stuck and do not know how to proceed in order to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/chewie lib will be used for playing m3u8 files

**Add Dependency**

```
dependencies:
  chewie: ^latest_version
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'url.m3u8');
  ChewieController chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample App"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Chewie(controller: chewieController),
        ));
  }
}
```